# No save rendered frames option while rendering animations in the latest version of Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, emission

I recently updated Blender 3.1.2. I hadn't updated in a while som I had to get used to some changes.

I have two questions.

While I render animations I usually press save pretty often so that if my computer crashes I still have the rendered frames and don't have to start from the beginning. Now in the latest version I can't press it, it's grey. In summary my question is "How do I save the rendered frames while rendering animations?"

I use Blender to do Star Wars shorts. It used to be very easy to use the compositor and add the Fog glow effect. But now in the latest verion the lightsaber isn't really that illuminated with a white core as it should be, not it's illuminated but not as much as I want to. I've tried to increase the emission shader but it's still the same.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Frames of animation are automatically written to the directory you define here:

[image]